# Change individual cell color when clicked in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there an Apps Script I could use that will allow me to change the background color of an individual cell (pre set color) when I left click on the cell? I am a teacher and need a way to quickly track whether students are on task and so would like to be able to just click a cell to record the observation (and would eventually like a timestamp generated when clicked as well).

I have used the conditional formatting for changing cell colors but cannot find a way to make a conditional format upon clicking a cell.

Answer (score 0):

There actually *is* a built-in function that triggers an action when a cell is selected - [onSelectionChange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee).

By default the function runs when you left-click ANY cell on ANY sheet.

So, you probably want to add some conditional logic (an IF statement) so you don't change the color of EVERY clicked cell.

Is there a particular sheet and particular column you can isolate for color-changing behavior?

By way of example, the script below will run whenever you click a cell:

- It checks if the cell you selected is in **column 1** of **"Sheet1"**.
- If not, the **return;** stops the script.
- If so, the cell's background color is changed to **red**.

Change the parameters in the IF statement and/or the color as needed for your use case, or remove the IF logic entirely if you want any cell clicked to change color.

```
function onSelectionChange(e) {
    if (!e)
      throw "Do not run onSelectionChange from Script Editor"
  const src = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const r = e.range;
  const col = r.getColumn();
  const row = r.getRow();
  
  if (src.getName() != "Sheet1" || col >1) return;{
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,col).setBackground("red");
  }
}
```

Comment: When I run this script (after requesting permission) it throws up a Unvarified Apps warning and stops me from executing it.  Any ideas why that is and a posible fix?

Comment: The script shouldn't be run from the Script Editor. How are you "running" the script? It should execute automatically when you click a cell in the sheet - assuming you've updated the parameters (eg change "Sheet1" to your sheet name).